# MSBuild doesn't work with C++ builds

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

Since a couple of weeks, MSBuild doesn't finish any builds anymore when I try to build a Visual C++ project in Visual Studio 2010.

In Process Explorer I can see that a subprocess MSBuild.exe is attached to devenv.exe, but no cl.exe is ever invoked. After 30 seconds another MSBuild.exe subprocess is attached and this continues for a while, until finally the build is aborted (or I kill Visual Studio).

[image: Visual Studio with MSBuild subprocesses]

I observed that after killing Visual Studio, the MSBuild processes are orphaned and if I restart Visual Studio and invoke another build, it suddenly works.

[image: Orphaned, but working MSBuild processes]

When every orphaned MSBuild process has exited, I cannot build anymore.

I tried to check, if there's anything wrong with the MSBuild installations, but at first sight it looks fine.

I reinstalled the SP1 of VS 2010 as well as Windows SDK 8.1, but nothing changed.

I also installed VS 2015 Express, which now ships with MSBuild (previously was shipped with .Net Framework), but same behavior.

The problem occurrs with different Visual C++ projects.

I could not google any solution, for slightly related problems there seemed to be issues with Avast antivirus. This is a corporate notebook, which is protected by Sophos, so I can't change any antivirus settings.

**EDIT1**

If I invoke MSBuild directly with

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe .\MyProj\MyProj.vcxproj

it just works.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: antivirus disabled?

Comment: This is in a corporate environment, therefor I can't disable antivirus.

Comment: Check for any errors in Event Viewer -- they might help get more information about problem with MSBuild.exe. If you find any, add to your question.

Comment: @Simon What's the result if you build project through MSBuild tool directly?

Comment: I had a similary problem with vs2013. I have deactivated all unnecessary plugins. Now it's work perfectly

Comment: @starain I've updated the question

Comment: Avast is bad but Sophos also has a reputation for its viral capabilities.  It in particular appears to dislike VS2010.  Something you should already have discovered by searching this site for "sophos", at which point you should have known that the version number is important.  Not that this is ever a good lead, you are going to have to ask corporate IT staff to help you out.  They are the only ones that can act on any suggestions from Sophos support.  Or provide you with something less aggressive so you can get your job done.

Comment: @starain: the Interaktion of VS with MSBuild seems not to work, so I would consider the tag MSBuild still valid.

Comment: In the mean time I got a new machine (regular leasing cycle) and the problem doesn't occur anymore. I suspect the reason for this issue may have been lack of drive space as my old machine was pretty full.